# Can Helicobacter pylori be eradicated naturally?

Tags: immunology, bacteriology, antibiotics, gastroenterology

This question is not to discuss whether substances that have anti-*H. pylori* activity work or not, or to discuss the pros and cons of such but from a medical perspective.

Assuming that one is able to control, reduce, or eliminate *H. pylori* via foods containing natural anti-bacterial activity targeted at *H. pylori* without the consumption of antibiotics, what is the possibility of reinfection or an overgrowth with *H. pylori*?

> In this study, the bactericidal activity of Korean and Japanese wasabi roots, stems and leaves against Helicobacter pylori were examined... All parts of wasabi showed bactericidal activities against H. pylori strain NCTC 11637, YS 27 and YS 50.

My questions are:

1. If this method was carried out *in vivo* and the results were found to be consistent with the research mentioned above, what is the chance of developing resistance to *H. pylori*?
2. Will developing resistance prevent recolonization of the stomach lining with *H. pylori*?

[Bactericidal activity of wasabi (Wasabia japonica) against Helicobacter pylori](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15246236)

Comment: Your sentence is quite confusing. Could you break it up in some meaningful way?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that you can clear H. pylori with foods? Can you share that?

Comment: To clarify - By eradication, I mean symptoms disappear, but not confirmed by testing.

Comment: Then you have not eradicated the infection.

Comment: Ok I tried, but here's what I've come up with http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15246236

Comment: So my questions is, if this method is carried out in-vivo, what is the chance of developing a resistance to h.pylori? And will developing a resistance prevent the re-colonization of the stomach lining?

Comment: +1 for showing your research. This is the response that saves a question from closure. I've edited your question to add the research and revised questions.

Comment: There is a flaw in your logic. You are saying that the foods have antibacterial properties and then say can the infection be eradicated without consuming an antibiotic. If you eating something that actually has antibacterial properties, then whether you like it or not, you are consuming an antibiotic. Just because it didn't come in a pill made by GlaxoWellcome, Pfizer, Merck, etc, doesn't mean it isn't an antibiotic, just that it hasn't been standardized, had safety and efficacy tests done, and been proven in clinical trials to be scientifically effective.

Answer (score 1):

H.pylori is a bacteria that is a cause for Peptic ulcer disease of human being. It helps to create more acidic product and causes ulcer. But human body is naturally protected to H.pylore, but excess stress,irregular life style etc helps H.pylori to growth and causes ulcer. Simple measure can escape you from this infection. 1. Intake enough water 2. Maintain oral hygiene is very Imp, 3, at bed time gurgle by H2o2 ( Hydrogen per Oxyde) 3. If you are infected then triple therapy for 3 weeks is the choice of treatment

Comment: Can you please add some references for your claim?

Comment: I am a registered physician and from that respect I answered

Comment: @fazlerabbi Still best to add references.

Comment: @fazlerabbi Great to have experts here. Still references are required. If they come from your practice, there should be something available like guidelines etc.

Comment: My answer was from my own knowledge,but Here I am giving a ref. Hope it will be helpful. JOHN HOPKINS MEDICINE Health Library (p00373)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you would want to eat lots of wasabi and the likes to decrease/eliminate the bacterial load of *H. pylori* in your body.

Concerning your questions -

1. to be perfectly blunt here - The chance to develop resistance to a bacterium by temporarily eating something is close to 0. This can be explained by two factors:

1 - resistance could develop spontaneously due to mutations and the likes, however the chance is incredibly low if not 0 (nothing in biology is ever impossible ;) ).

2 - if you only temporarily consume an antibiotic substance you will only be protected as long as the substance is active in your system. Surely you could eat wasabi every day, but would you want to for the rest of your life? Additionally, resistance to bacterial pathogens seems to be a temporal situation since their "ability" to incorporate foreign DNA into their own arsenal as well as spontaneous mutations turns the pathogens into ever changing organisms and while you might have been resistant to the "old" bacterium, the newly mutated or modified version could still harm you - unfortunately (This is one of the reasons why it is so hard to develop anti bacterial vaccines).

2. If - and only if! - you would be resistant to the bacterium, than this should in theory protect you from further colonization of said bacterium. As previously mentioned this is a currently very unlikely scenario due to the limitations science is facing.

IF sources shall be needed just comment and I will search the web for something suitable ;) Hell, I might even get the chance to cite some of my own papers, finally ;)

Comment: Yes please add sources to allow users to background read on your answer

Answer (score 0):

There is many possible antibacterial natural treatment using probiotics provided by natural product such kambucha,Baikkimchi,kefir ***(1,2,3)***.In the other side,plant oil extracts also studied in vivo and in vitro ***(4,5,6)*** ,but in  general, all result was relative that we can not be cured 100% with such therapy.
source:

1. http://nordicfoodlab.org/blog/2013/2/komboooucha
2. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs13765-014-4198-6
3. http://www.ijaaonline.com/article/S0924-8579(05)00054-3/abstract?cc=y=
4. http://cmr.asm.org/content/12/4/564.short
5. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1348-0421.2004.tb03521.x/full
6. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378874107004370

Comment: Which of those links are you claiming shows in vivo efficasy in humans?  Because as far as I can tell, none of them do.